# regex validator for querySelectorAll argument

Tags: javascript, css, regex, css-selectors, selectors-api

I have written very basic regex to validate argument of querySelectorAll() method.
Validated for some random values and seems it's working fine.

I just wanted to know if some improvement can be done or not.

It's possible that some validation will be missed by regex, but my main question is about my approach, about the way I have written this regex.
Also I am pretty new to regex. Please point me if I am doing any major mistake performance wise.

```
var p = /^([A-Za-z0-6]*|\*)?((?:(?:#|\.|:|\[)[-A-za-z0-9()+\s"=|^$*]+)*)$/;

/* 


[A-Za-z0-6]* Type selector
\* Universal selector
#|\.|:|\[ for id,class,attribute and psuedo classes
[-A-za-z0-9()+\s"=|^$*]+ id,class, attribute or pseudo class value


*/

var stringArray = [
"div",
"div:first-child",
"div#id",
"div123",
"h1",
"*.warning",
".warning",
"*#myid",
"#myid",
"p.pastoral.marine",
"h1#chapter1",
"*#z98y",
"a.external:visited",
"a:visited",
"a:focus:hover",
"tr:nth-child(2n+1)",
"tr:nth-child(odd)",
"p:nth-child(4n+4)",
"foo:nth-child(0n+5)",
"foo:nth-child(5)",
":nth-child( 3n + 1 )",
"img:nth-of-type(2n+1)",
"h2:nth-of-type(n+2):nth-last-of-type(n+2)",
"h2:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type)",
"h1[title]",
'span[class="example"]',
'span[hello="Cleveland"][goodbye="Columbus"]',
'a[hreflang|="en"]',
'object[type^="image"]',
'a[href$=".html"]',
'p[title*="hello"]'
];
```

Comment: These RegExes will only match specifics. Is that what you want, or general selectors? If so; you need different (and probably less) RegEx matches.

Comment: .. `a b`, `a > b`, `a + b`, `a ~ b`, etc.. and `a::before`, `a::after`, `a::first-letter`, etc. Are CSS selectors really something that can be checked in this way?

Comment: Yes Paul, I am just looking for simple selector sequence without combinator

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps JSCSSP would be of use to you, use parsing rather than a regex? http://www.glazman.org/JSCSSP/

Comment: This sounds like something better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ than StackOverflow.

Comment: @PK: How do you know that they can be checked in this way (I assume that's what your Yes means)? Theoretically the most accurate way to validate a selector for use with `querySelectorAll()` would be to just call it and see if it throws an exception, but that may cause unnecessary performance overhead.

Comment: It will be possible, but hard to manage, illegible and most likely a larger overhead than just running it, as mentioned by @BoltClock

Answer (score 0):

The most concise and reliable way to validate a selector for `querySelectorAll` is to call the function itself and check if it throws:

```js
const validateSelector = selector => {
  try { document.querySelectorAll(selector) }
  catch { return false }
  return true;
}

console.log(validateSelector('abc!?#&^123')); // false
console.log(validateSelector('div > text')); // true
```